# Авторизация пользователей на REST сервере с помощью OAuth2

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mvc, oauth2

Подскажите,пожалуйста, есть REST сервер.Ищу второй день, никак не могу найти толковой информации о реализации аутентификации пользователей, OAuth2 на Spring MVC с хранением токенов в базе.Примеров с Spring Boot полно, но по ним не могу разобраться.
Есть ли какой-то толковый туториал? Это все должно реализовываться в одном файле xml? Скажите, как вы решали подобные задачи

Comment: Это сложно, лучше уже брать готовое решение, а зачем вам это надо?

Comment: Есть Android приложение, которое использует методы на сервере через REST, для аутентификации пользователей приложения нужно использовать такую систему. Какие есть готовые решения?

Comment: @Иван, вот тут можете посмотреть: https://github.com/mohaxspb/springSecurityExample